# Parse Cloud Code : Doing a httpRequest within another httpRequest

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, httprequest

I'm trying to do a httpRequest within another. I'll explain what I'm doing.

I am retrieving some datas from a Parse table (GET request) and, if this request succeed, I want to to another GET request to another Parse table, and unfortunately my second http Request didn't work at all, it didn't even finish as success or error.

This is what I have until now.

```
function getUserInformations(deviceId)
{
    var response = new Parse.Promise();
    var userInfos;
    var apiKey = <<API Key>>;
    var url = "http://api.timezonedb.com/?zone=";

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User",
        headers: {
            "X-Parse-Application-Id": <<Application Id>>,
            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": <<REST API Key>>,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
            var x;
            var count = 0;

            for (x in jsonObject.results)
            {
                if (jsonObject.results.hasOwnProperty(x))
                    count++;
            }
            for (x = 0; x < count; x++)
            {
                if (jsonObject.results[x].deviceId == deviceId)
                    break;
            }
            if (x < count && jsonObject.results[x].deviceId == deviceId)
            {
                userInfos.email = jsonObject.results[x].email;
                userInfos.name = jsonObject.results[x].name;
            }
            url += userInfos.timeZone;
            url += "&format=json&key=";
            url += apiKey;

            Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                method: "GET",
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                },
                success: function(httpResponse) {
                    var timestamp = httpResponse.data.timestamp;
                    var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
                    var hours = date.getHours();
                    var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
                    var time = hours + minutes.substr(-2);
                },
                error: function(httpResponse) {
                }
            });

            response.resolve(userInfos);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.reject(userInfos);
        }
    });
    return (response);
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure that the `timezonedb.com` site allows cross-origin requests?

Comment: I'm new to http requests, so I didn't knew that some sites didn't allows those kind of requests. It may be the problem, I'll try to find another API instead of timezonedb